# Unable to print data in grid

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I am trying to print my data coming from controller in a table but unable to do so. I am using Kendo UI `template` in order to print. I am attaching the code below along with the error that I am getting.

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script>

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/default1/KendoDataAjaxHandle/',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {


                    //Get the external template definition using a jQuery selector
                    var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());

                    console.log(result);
                    var data = template(result); //Execute the template
                    $("#example").html(data); //Append the result

                }
            })

</script>

<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>Customer name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            # for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++){ #
            <tr>
                # for (var j=0; j < result[i].length; j++){ #
                <td>
                    #= result[j] #
                </td>
                # } #
            </tr>
            # } #
        </tbody>
    </table>

</script>
```

What i am doing in the above code is making an ajax call to the action method and getting the results in JSON. Here's my controller method:

```
public ActionResult KendoDataAjaxHandle([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IQueryable<Customer> products = db.Customers;
            DataSourceResult result = products.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Error that I am getting on executing the code is: **result is undefined.** However on consoling the results returned after ajax call, I get an object which has all the values.

How do I print those values coming back in the table? Also please correct me if I have done something wrong here. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the the variable name referenced inside the template from "result" to "data" as that is what Kendo uses in its template execution code.

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/ENUze

**Updated Example**
Showing how to iterate the object's fields(based on comment):
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/oXOJU

NOTE: this assumes that the fields are listed in the order you have specified in your comment.  If the fields don't come back in this order, you will have to add code to map the field name to the column index instead of just blindly looping.

**Update 2:**

Updated example using exact format of returned data:

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/ipeHec

Note: you have to deal with the CustomerAltID that is in the returned data but not in the table somehow.  My example chooses to remove it from list of keys to process.  How you deal with it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen. The error seems to have gone after changing `result` to `data`. But i don't see any data in the table now. My returned array is a key value pair as  CustomerAltID:"IMI-001"  CustomerID:1    CustomerName:"Henry Ford"   Gender:"M". How do I iterate through this. Can you please show it in dojo. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried with your updated code and on hardcoding the values, I get the result but when I try to get data from the controller it again shows no data. This is what i get when I console.log(result)    `Object {Data: Array[15], Total: 15, AggregateResults: null, Errors: null}`

Comment: What is in the Array[15]?  Usually what you get back is {"Data":[{"Field1":Value1,"Field2":Value2...}, {"Field1":Value1,"Field2":Value2...},...],"Total"...}  You have to write your template code so that it matches the schema of the returned data.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the format in which I am getting the data. Any suggestions as to how to print it in table.

Comment: What is contained in the Array[15]...you need to post the contents of at least one of the objects in the array to show the format of the data.  You can do that in the dev tools console or by looking at the response of the request on the Network tab in dev tools...there is no way you are literally getting "Array[15]" back as the data...that array *has* to contain 15 actual objects.

Comment: `{"Data":[{"CustomerID":1,"CustomerAltID":"IMI-001","CustomerName":"Henry Ford","Gender":"M"},{"CustomerID":2,"CustomerAltID":"IMI-002","CustomerName":"Bill Gates","Gender":"M"}...` . This is the data that I am getting back.

Comment: I got the answer. I was missing one part which is instead of giving `result` to template as parameter, I should have given `result.Data`. But thanks for your help. Upvoting your answer.

Comment: I've update my answer with a dojo using the exact data format anyway.